# Nemiver shows ASM only

Tags: c, debugging

I am new to nemiver and I am trying to debug C-Code.
So I compile it first using Geany, then I type following in the shell:

> nemiver source

nemiver opens and all is well, except the fact that I am seeing ASM-Code only.
I can't switch to the "source-view" (C-Code).

What should I do in order to see C-Code to debug?

Answer (score 2):

You should build your binary with debug symbols ("-g" will give you basic debug info with gcc). When you do that, Nemiver will be able to find the source files and will in fact open the source files automatically as needed.